# angular dragdrop beforeDrop callback

Tags: angularjs, callback, drag

I try to get the dragged object and test the drag object before dropping it, how can I obtain it on beforeDrop callback? I can see the 'dndDragItem' after the drop action, but can't get it before the drop, any idea on how to achieve it? Thanks!

Angular dragdrop plugin used
https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop

The following is my related code

html

```
<div ng-repeat="ap in aps track by $index" 
                    class="panel panel-primary"
                    data-drop="true" 
                    data-jqyoui-options=""
                    ng-model="newTagsData[$index][ap.ipaddr]" 
                    jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, beforeDrop: 'profileDrop(evt, ui)'}"
```

controller

```
//check logic before drop
        $scope.profileDrop = function(evt, ui){
            var dropItem = this.dndDragItem;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
```

When dropped, I can get the draggable object I desired
[image]

But I want the draggable object before drop, I then place a debugger in the beforeDrop callback, but this time, I can't get my drggable object which I will need to do the logic and decide whether it is allowable to drop
[image]

Appreciate all bro for any help

Comment: Working on a similar problem now, any chance you can share the rest of your code to see how you solved it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save the object to a scope variable (or save it in a service object) when you start dragging the object

```
jqyoui-draggable="{ onStart:'registerDraggedItem(item)'}
```

and then reference that in your beforeDrop function.